# What's the type of (2*3.14f)?

Tags: c, types, sizeof

I just wrote something to test the `sizeof` operator.

Firstly, when I build this program, GCC give me a warning.

```
main(){
    printf("%d", (2*3.14f));
}
// test.c|2|warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int',
// but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
```

So GCC believes the type of `(2*3.14f)` is `double`.

Then I added a `sizeof` operator, I assume the output will be exactly 8, which is the size of `double`.

```
main(){
    printf("%d", sizeof(2*3.14f));
}
//Output: 4
```

This is really confusing. So the question is: what is the type of `(2*3.14f)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(2*3.14f)` has type `float`. It is promoted to `double` when passed to a variadic function, hence the reference to `double` in the error message from GCC.

If you wish to display a `float` converted to `int`, use `printf("%d", (int)…);`

If you wish to display the bits of a `float` as if it were an `int`, use:

```
int i;
assert(sizeof(f) == sizeof(i));
memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof(f));
printf("%d", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both invocations have undefined behaviour. Indeed, the first argument has type `double` and the second `size_t`, so you must use format specifiers `%f` and `%zu`, respectively.

(The type of `2 * 3.14f` is `float`, because of the usual arithmetic conversions, but the argument is promoted to `double` under the floating point conversions because you're passing it as a variable argument.)